# How to develop a URL scraper to scrape all the user profile URL of any Facebook group using PHP or other PLs?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

What is the approach and way of programming.
Suppose https://www.facebook.com/groups/infonetbd/ is a group link.
I want such a web application that I can extract the user URL of about 20,000 members. can any one give me details if it is possible or am I going to face security issues... simply as if we visit user profile and similarly the web app may visit all the URLs within few minutes and copy and paste the browser address bar URL it gets and store in required database.

Comment: I wonder why will you need such a large amount of user data...???

Comment: This is our  group and we want to make a list of user and categorize them as they are using our free services and we want to summarize our performance and do some identification based on their activity and requests and other participations.

Comment: can you tell me how it is possible to do?